# Excel VLOOKUP on Table with Duplicate rows

Tags: excel

I'm trying to do a vlookup in a table that has duplicate rows. How would I do the below? We have a table which records all the banners created for a specific offer. For a future offer, I want to do a lookup to get the latest banner created for that offer.

```
offer   creative    create date
a           v1          10-Jan
a           v2          20-Jan
a           v3          30-Jan

i want the below. how do I get v3 in the below cell.        

offer   creative    
a           should be v3
```

Comment: Do you control the data? If so, simply sort the data by Create Date (Newest to Oldest) and Vlookup will always find the newest version first.

Comment: No, we don't control the data so I need a formula. I'm playing with Index/match functions but no luck yet.

Answer (score 0):

u can use MAX-IF formula to find maximum value for each unique name

```
{=MAX(IF($A$2:$A$4=A2;$C$2:$C$4))}
```

(dont forget to pres Ctrl+Shift+Enter after writing the formula)

then u can use IF formula to control the date is equal to the latest date.

```
=IF(D2=C2;B2;"")
```

finally u can use VLOOKUP-IF to find what u need

```
{=VLOOKUP("a";IF($E$2:$E$4<>"";$A$2:$E$4);5;0)}
```